# Redirigir segun el dominio

Tags: javascript, redirección, dominio

Hola amigos estoy buscando la manera correcta de redirigir según de donde viene la visita .

Tengo este código:

```
 <script>
var result = document.referrer.split( '/' ).indexOf("https://ged-botxtrem.rhcloud.com/");;
if (result >= 0){
    alert("Correcto");
} else {
    alert("Incorrecto");
    location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
}
</script>
```

El funciona bien pero resulta que cuando la url es :

```
https://ged-botxtrem.rhcloud.com/index.php
```

O otra variante. Que no sea solo el dominio.

Redirecciona igual como que no es el dominio correcto .

Espero alguna ayuda Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Por qué no usas regex?

```js
var url = document.referrer;
var rgx;

rgx = new RegExp("https?\:\/\/es\.stackoverflow\.com\/");

//En tu caso
//rgx = new RegExp("https?:\/\/ged\-botxtrem\.rhcloud\.com\/");

if(rgx.test(url))
  console.log("Correcto");
else
  console.log("Incorrecto");
```

Comment: Cuando se usa el constructor de RegExp, hay que escapar cada barra (2 barras). Por ejemplo, este código coincide con `http://esXstackoverflowYcom/`. Además, deberías anclarlo al inicio del texto con `^` para evitar algo como `http://url?x=otra_url`... De todas formas, es más sencillo declararlo sin el constructor: `var rgx = /^https?:\/\/es\.stackoverflow\.com\//i;`

Answer (score 1):

[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/indexOf)

El método indexOf()devuelve el índice, dentro del objeto String que realiza la llamada, de la primera ocurrencia del valor especificado, comenzando la búsqueda desde indiceBusqueda; o -1 si no se encuentra dicho valor.

Es decir, que si `https://ged-botxtrem.rhcloud.com/index.php` **contiene** `https://ged-botxtrem.rhcloud.com/`  y en tu ejemplo siempre será verdadero, retornará un valor distinto a -1.

Si lo que quieres es verificar que las cadenas **coincidan o sean iguales**, debes comparar los string con [localeCompare](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_localecompare.asp)

```
 <script>
var result = document.referrer.split( '/' ).localeCompare("https://ged-botxtrem.rhcloud.com/");;
if (result >= 0){
    alert("Correcto");
} else {
    alert("Incorrecto");
    location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hola gracias por el dato pero no funciona da igual de donde venga la visita no hay direccionamiento